# Simple HTML Dom Parser - Finding img based on alt tag

Tags: html, image, dom, alt

I'm using the Simple HTML DOM parser to try and pick up the href of an img tag where the alt attribute is alt=" map" (space is intentional). This is the code I'm using:

```
$result = $page->find("img[alt= map]",0)->href;
```

But when an expected match is in the html it doesn't pick it up. Where am i going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `href` attribute for the [`img` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#the-img-element). You probably want [`src`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#attr-img-src).